# Python weakref.proxy object considered iterable?

Tags: python, weak-references, iterable

I came across the following (using Python 3.8.3):

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from weakref import proxy

class Dummy:
   pass

isinstance(d := Dummy, Iterable)
# False (as expected)

isinstance(p := proxy(d), Iterable)
# True (why?!)

for _ in p:
    # raises TypeError
    pass
```

How could the proxy object pass the iterable-test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides `__iter__` in case the underlying type provides it. `__iter__` *must* be implemented on the type to work, not the instance, so it can't conditionally define `__iter__` without fragmenting into many different classes, not just a single `proxy` class.

Unfortunately, the `Iterable` test just checks if the class defines `__iter__`, not whether it works, and `proxy` doesn't know if it *really* works without calling the wrapped class's `__iter__`. If you want to check for iterability, just iterate it, and catch the `TypeError` if it fails. If you can't iterate it immediately, while it's subject to time-of-check/time-of-use race conditions, you could write your own simple tester that covers whether it can *actually* be iterated:

```
def is_iterable(maybeiter):
    try:
        iter(maybeiter)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```